# Django ManyToMany field returns None but it has related records

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with a ManyToMany field, but when I make a query, this field returns `None` even when it has values in the database (I have checked it with Django Admin util).

This is my model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    cities = models.ManyToManyField(City, related_name='profiles', verbose_name=_('City'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Profile')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Profiles')

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}]{}".format(self.name, self.cities)
```

This is my query:

```
profile_city = models.Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)

print(profile_city.id, ' ', profile_city.name, ' ', profile_city.cities)
```

And this is the result in console:

```
1   Quintana Roo   GeneralApp.City.None
```

When I try to iterate over ´Profile.cities´, I get this error:
´TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable´.

I am new to Django and I thought ManyToMany fields returned an array, but It is not, apparently.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, it returns `GeneralApp.City.None`, and `Profile.cities`, is ineed not iterable, it should be `some_profile.cities` (so you can only access the related once with a `Profile` **object**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`profile_city = models.Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)`

`profile_city.cities` returns a manager class which you cannot iterate.

Try this instead of **profile_city.cities**

```
profile_city.cities.all()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it's work with this 'profile_city.cities.all()' and I could get all the values.